# how can I modify my JSON result?

Tags: php, json, highcharts

when I return my array by I got `[{"product":"TEST_1","best_selling_product":"305"},{"product":"IPHONE 4S","best_selling_product":"108"}]` , but Highcharts dont let me use string as value then how can I change it to int or float?  my backend function is this

```
function best_selling_product(){
        $sql = "SELECT product,SUM(sale_detail.amount) AS best_selling_product FROM sale_detail INNER JOIN product ON sale_detail.idproduct = product.idproduct GROUP BY sale_detail.idproduct ORDER BY SUM(sale_detail.amount) DESC LIMIT 0,5"; 
        $result = $this->conexion->conexion->query($sql);
        $array = array();
        while($record = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $array[] = $record;
        }
        return $array;
        $this->conexion->cerrar();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function, set the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `CAST` in the mysql query, or process the data in php using `floatval()` or `intval()`.

For example in the mysql query:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(sale_detail.amount) as UNSIGNED) AS best_selling_product FROM ...
```

OR with php:

```
while($record = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $record['best_selling_product'] = floatval($record['best_selling_product']);
    $array[] = $record;
}
```